# How to print object's values with "annotate()" and "for loop" in ascending order?

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have `Category` and `Product` models below. *I use **Django 3.2.16**:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Then, when running `test` view to print `id`, `name` and `product__count` with [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and **index** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from .models import Category
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db.models import Count

def test(request):
    qs = Category.objects.annotate(Count('product'))

    print(qs[0].id, qs[0].name, qs[0].product__count)
    print(qs[1].id, qs[1].name, qs[1].product__count)
    print(qs[2].id, qs[2].name, qs[2].product__count)
    print(qs[3].id, qs[3].name, qs[3].product__count)
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

These are printed in ascending order properly as shown below:

```
1 Fruits 14
2 Vegetables 10
3 Meat 4
4 Fish 3
```

But, when running `test` view to print `id`, `name` and `product__count` with [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and **for loop** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):
    qs = Category.objects.annotate(Count('product'))

    for obj in qs:
        print(obj.id, obj.name, obj.product__count)
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

These are printed in descending order improperly as shown below:

```
4 Fish 3
2 Vegetables 10
3 Meat 4
1 Fruits 14
[25/Jan/202
```

In addition, when running `test` view to print `id` and `name` with [all()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all) and **index** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):
    qs = Category.objects.all()

    print(qs[0].id, qs[0].name)
    print(qs[1].id, qs[1].name)
    print(qs[2].id, qs[2].name)
    print(qs[3].id, qs[3].name)
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

And, when running `test` view to print `id` and `name` with [all()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all) and **for loop** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):
    qs = Category.objects.all()

    for obj in qs:
        print(obj.id, obj.name)
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

These are printed in ascending order properly as shown below:

```
1 Fruits 14
2 Vegetables 10
3 Meat 4
4 Fish 3
```

So, how can I print object's values with `annotate()` and **for loop** in ascending order properly?

Answer (score 0):

Without any order by, you can not make any assumptions on the order. When subscripting, and the queryset is not ordered, Django will order by primary key to prevent returning the same record multiple times. You can order with:

```
def test(request):
    qs = Category.objects.annotate(Count('product')).order_by('pk')

    for obj in qs:
        print(obj.id, obj.name, obj.product__count)

    return HttpResponse('Test')
```